# Usar variable en lugar de nombre de columna en un UPDATE PDO y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy tratando de hacer un **UPDATE** con **PDO** donde **desconozco la columna que debe ser editada**.

En mi caso, tengo varias columnas (1, 2, 3, 4...) y estas representan los días del mes. Previamente uso `$date = date('j', time());` para obtener el día de hoy, ya que es donde se deben hacer los cambios.

El problema es que **no sé como indicar el nombre de la columna** haciendo uso de una variable. He probado con esto:

```
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users_stats SET ".$date." = ".$date." + :date");
```

Y como hoy es día 4, estoy intentando que el update quede así: `UPDATE users_stats SET 4 = 4 + :date"`

Comment: El nombre de las columnas son números? , debe tener en cuenta que el nombre de la tabla ni de las columnas se pueden parámetrizar en una consulta preparada.

Comment: Sí, el nombre de la tabla es 1, 2, 3, ... ¿Entonces cómo lo hago? No puedo hacer un if para cada caso...

Comment: @Dev.Joel No lo entiendo muy bien. Si quieres, publicalo como una respuesta con el ejemplo completo, por favor. $date es el día de hoy (nombre de la columa) y :date se recibe desde bindParam con el valor a añadirle a la columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para las consultas preparadas **no se puede parametrizar los valores para nombres de tablas o de columnas**, a partir de este concepto puede generar su query de la siguiente forma.

Un detalle adicional, como su columna tiene como nombre un número, deberá encerrarla en *comillas invertidas* o  `back-ticks`

```
$date = date('j', time());
$sentencia = $dbcon->prepare("UPDATE users_stats SET `$date` = :date + :date");
// pasamos el valor del parámetro con nombre date, _(de tipo INT para la suma)_
$sentencia->bindParam(':date', $date,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sentencia->execute(); // ejecutamos la consulta.
```

Comment: Eran las comillas invertidas.. Gracias.